# Young boy protagonist with a sword containing a red stone on its hilt?

Tags: shin-hakkenden

It was in a modern day world with guns and wars, there was some kind of armed conflict going on.

The story was about seven powerful crystals or gems or rounded stones, each carried by a different person wielding it in a way that suits his fighting:

- One of them had it embedded in his shield, it was green I believe
- One of the characters also carried his stone around and played with cards
- The main protagonist had it in the hilt of his sword I think

In one of the scenes the boy was shown to have been born with the stone in his hand.

By the end of the series they were trying to unite the power of the stones to defeat some kind of enemy.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is http://myanimelist.net/anime/10156/Sacred_Seven but I doubt its what you're looking for as it doesn't met most of your description

Comment: it also reminds me with [Rave Master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rave_Master) but it has too much differences with the one you describe

Answer (score 8):

I think it could be **[Shin Hakkenden](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1988)** (1999, 26 episodes)

> The year is 2588 in the system of Godworld and its eight satellites. Humanity came here in the distant past, after a long journey across the stars from Earth. Now the system is ruled by a loose coalition of powerful families: House Owari, House Meed, and House Iigy. The story begins when Kai, the heir to House Owari, attacks an icy planet. Living in a humble village on the surface is Kou, a young boy who is perpetually arguing with his father. When Kai's navy arrives, Kou takes his father's mighty Murasame sword to fight back, and his adventures begin. A sci-fi remake of Hakkenden. (Plot from [Animevice](http://www.animevice.com/shin-hakkenden/11-4852/)).

This is a picture of the main character **Kou** who has a red gem in his sword (You can also see a dog with an eyepatch: it hide a yellow gem in one of his teeth).

[image: A pic]

This is **Jinrai** who has a green gem in his shield.

[Another pic http://gallery.animeinfo.ru/img/Jinrai-125835-57413-1.jpg](http://gallery.animeinfo.ru/img/Jinrai-125835-57413-1.jpg)

This is **Tomoka** who has a blue gem in a dice: he is a gambler and use cards also for fighting.

[image: Tomoka]

Answer (score 3):

The anime you are looking for might be Deltora Quest

[image]

> The Seven Gems of Deltora are taken from The Belt of Deltora and scattered over the most feared places in Deltora and The Shadow Lord takes over Deltora. King Endon who was supposed to be the protector of the Belt which protected the land, somehow vanished from the land to leave his people in the mercy of the tyrant for 16 years.
>   On Lief's sixteenth birthday after narrowly escaping the Grey Guards, he is presented with the Belt of Deltora, given a task to gather the 7 gems and to find the heir to the throne in order to rid Deltora of the evil Shadow Lord once and for all. He is also given a sword, an invisibility cloak, a rough map of where the gems were to be and a travelling companion named Barda who was long known as a beggar before revealing himself as one of the palace guards. He and Barda leave city of Del and enter the Forests of Silence where they are attacked by the Wenn and paralyzed. They are woken up by a mysterious girl named Jasmine, who at first believed them as Grey Guards and only intended to rob them and leave them to be eaten by the Wennbar. However, after being persuaded by an old tree that told her that they were not Grey Guards, she comes and saves them with an antidote that freed them from the paralysis.

The main protagonist is a young boy set out on a quest by his father to find the gems and put them together to defeat the evil tyrant.

He runs into different people and places that have the gems.

I found the information from the [Deltora Quest wikia](http://deltoraquest.wikia.com/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(anime)).

Comment: I don't think it is Deltora Question having watched it before because it is not set in the modern world with guns but rather magic and sword fighting. Also I know there was a sword in it, but it did not have a green gem in it and plus the gem was taken out and placed into the Belt of Deltora.

Comment: It might not be it. but i gave him information on it to see if it is. i would rather leave him a comment but can't since i dont have enough rep

Comment: It can't be Deltora Quest, 1) it's not modern day and even the Grey Guard's projectile weapons you can't call guns 2) the Gems from the Belt of Deltora are guarded by monsters and they only work if on the Belt (with the exception to a couple of the guardians) and 3) the Belt of Deltora was created so long ago that none of the character could have been born with it in one of their hands. the only thing that Deltora Quest matches to the Question is that the Gems are used on the Belt to defeat the Shadow Lord